# DataFrame.resample ('M') does not give the monthly AVERAGE value but just the monthly total sum

Tags: python, pandas

I have the table below contain in the DataFrame df_pivoted:
                  
        cost          cost          cost          val1          val1          val1    
user_id             1         2         3         1         2         3   
timestamp                                                               
01/01/2011        1                     100       3                   5   
01/02/2011                    20                            8             
01/07/2012        19                            57                      
01/11/2012                            3100                              49  
21/12/2012                  240                           30            
14/09/2013        21                            63                      
01/12/2013                            3200                              51

I would like to calculate the AVERAGE monthly cost but the statement df_monthly = pivoted.resample ('M') does not return the average but only the sum of the value for the months. Also, I would like to know how I can calculate these average cost for each field associated to each user ('cost', 'val1',etc).

The code use in order to obtain the above table is :

```
import pandas as pd

newnames = ['timestamp','user_id', 'cost', 'val1','val2', 'val3','code']
df = pd.read_csv('mytest.csv', names = newnames, header = False, parse_dates=True, dayfirst=True)
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], dayfirst=True) 
pivoted = df.pivot('timestamp', 'user_id')
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: your table up top is formatted something nasty. please fix it.

Comment: Average per what? Per day in the month? Per day you have a record for?

Answer (score 1):

see the docs http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html You need to specify how you want the resample done eg sum or mean.. you can specify by field... The default is mean,, not exactly sure why you are getting sum instead.

Comment: Can you please provide an example of right syntax using down- or re-sampling? Because I just tried pivoted.resample('M',how='re-sampling') but I receive the error message 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 're-sampling'.

Comment: It tried it but it returns the same than pivoted.resample('M', how='sum').

Comment: Check your pandas version?

Comment: My panda version is 0.13.1